# Easier way to rename all the TextViews in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently have a fragment with a bunch of card things I made. I'm trying to find an easier way to rename each of the textview's inside each card with data from an ArrayList containing "ScheduleEntry" instances. Any advice is appreciated!

**XML Layout**

http://pastebin.com/B8Nn9ZV0

**Java Fragment**

http://pastebin.com/a9LiSuDw

**ScheduleEntry.java**

```
    package club.spiralsolutions.witsmobile;

    public class ScheduleEntry {
    public int getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }

    public void setPeriod(int period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public int getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(int average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    private int period;
    private String name;
    private int ID;
    private String teacher;
    private String room;
    private int average;

    public ScheduleEntry()
    {

    }

    public ScheduleEntry(int period, String name, int ID, String teacher, String room, int average)
    {
        this.period = period;
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.room = room;
        this.average = average;
    }
    public ScheduleEntry(int period, String name, int ID, String teacher, String room)
    {
        this.period = period;
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.room = room;

    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the view you want to display because by reading the code it seams to be a list of card views , I'm I correct ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Here is a picture.[Link](http://i.gyazo.com/99da9c894ca8e1033276e0f33e80b2d8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a list of card views , you could use `RecyclerView` which is availble in the v7 support library , here's a great training tutorial from the android developer website :

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html